# Spring OAuth2 with Proxy using Credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

Good morning.
We are developing an application which needs access to the internet for reaching the OAuth2.0 server. The problem is, that the configuration of the cloud blocks all internet access, which is not handled by a proxy. For authentication with the proxy we are provided with some credentials. Using the newest Spring boot version and the newest version of Spring Security, the whole team (hobby devs, and free / hobby project, nothing commercial) has no idea on how to setup the SpringSecurityOAuthFilterChain to make all OAuth calls using the proxy with credentials.

Here is our current FilterChain

```
    http //
            .authorizeHttpRequests() //
            .requestMatchers(PAGE_AUTH_SSO_LOGIN, PAGE_AUTH_ERROR, LOGIN_OAUTH2_CALLBACK_URL,
                    AuthenticationUtils.FAILURE_OAUTH_LOGIN_CALLBACK,
                    SpringConstants.ACTUATOR_HEALTH_URL).permitAll() //
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //
            .and() //
            .oauth2Login() //
                .loginPage(PAGE_AUTH_SSO_LOGIN)//
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> //
                        response.sendRedirect(SUCCESSFUL_OAUTH_LOGIN_CALLBACK)) //
                .failureHandler((request, response, authentication) -> //
                        response.sendRedirect(AuthenticationUtils.FAILURE_OAUTH_LOGIN_CALLBACK)) //
            .and() //
            .logout() //
            .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL) //
            .logoutSuccessUrl(
                    "/oauth2/authorization/logout?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8090/page/auth/ssoLogin.xhtml") //
            .clearAuthentication(true) //
            .invalidateHttpSession(true) //
            .deleteCookies(JSESSIONID) //
            .and() //
            .csrf().disable();
```

Setting the parameters for the JVM did not work. Can someone give us a hint or a working example on how to solve this problem?

Version of spring boot and spring boot security 3.0.1
Version of spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client: 3.0.1